# Do you need to normalize labels for models other than neural nets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, normalization, dependent-variable

As mentioned [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22776/is-it-valuable-to-normalize-rescale-labels-in-neural-network-regression?rq=1), normalizing the target variable often helps a neural network converge faster.
Does it help in convergence, or is there otherwise a reason to use it, for any type of model other than neural nets?